# Using jq group_by and count to sort JSON output from curl into sorted and counted list

Tags: json, curl, group-by, count, jq

Can anyone help me to understand and assist with a jq script please (only using jq)? Can anyone help me to write a script to take the output of:

```
`curl --silent "https://api.surfshark.com/v3/server/clusters" | jq`
```

and list the number of servers in each **countryCode** and the **min** and **max** loadings on those servers, **sorted by countryCode**?

```
.countryCode 'count of number of servers' 'lowest .load' 'highest .load'
AU    5    13%       30%
UK   10    35%       88%
US   25    12%       50%
```

etc....

I believe the use of group_by, or a combination of that and map, set path, get path and count may work, but I'm hoping someone with higher skills can help me.

Each json entry looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "country": "Albania",
    "**countryCode**": "AL",
    "region": "Europe",
    "regionCode": "EU",
    "**load**": 12,
    "id": "4c333aa2-d08b-4d11-9073-61c351ce1c1e",
    "coordinates": {
      "longitude": 19.8188889,
      "latitude": 41.3275
    },
    "info": [
      {
        "id": "55994450-0c87-4df3-b585-3836c67a863d",
        "entry": {
          "value": "U2FsdGVkX1/VX5IKc3H3ruClgbw7JgnqW7Eacumx8aM="
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "generic",
    "location": "Tirana",
    "**connectionName**": "al-tia.prod.surfshark.com",
```

Extract from another post referencing some of the possible commands

```
'map(.Properties.ItmId)
| reduce .[] as $i (
    {}; setpath([$i]; getpath([$i]) + 1)
  )
| to_entries | .[] | { "ItemId": .key, "Count": .value }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the `group_by` first and then derive the rest of the fields from there

```
group_by(.countryCode) 
  | map([ .[0].countryCode, length, min_by(.load).load, max_by(.load).load])
```

**EDIT**: Removed the redundant sort as pointed out by @peak

You could optionally add `.[] | @tsv` to get the table structure that you have in the question

Comment: `group_by` does the sorting.